# Sendmail + m4 - problem converting mc files into cf

Tags: linux, convert, sendmail

I'm currently trying to configure sendmail fo the first time and setup a mail server on a small embedded computer ( running a custom linux distribution ).

I'm having an issue with the m4 macros:

I'm trying to convert this:

```
VERSIONID(`$Id: generic-linux.mc,v 8.1 1999/09/24 22:48:05 gshapiro Exp $')
OSTYPE(linux)dnl
DOMAIN(generic)dnl
define(HELPFILE, `/etc/mail/helpfile')
FEATURE(nouucp, `noscpecial')
MAILER(local)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
```

to sendmail.cf, but all the output I get when running m4 is:

```
VERSIONID($Id: generic-linux.mc,v 8.1 1999/09/24 22:48:05 gshapiro Exp $)
OSTYPE(linux)DOMAIN(generic)
FEATURE(nouucp, noscpecial)
MAILER(local)MAILER(smtp)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to tell the macro processor about the cf.m4 file like this:

```
m4 /path/to/cf.m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
```